# What is the correct Xcode setting for Position Independent Executables

Tags: xcode, linker, pie-chart

Just recently started getting a post appstore submission email with the following advice.

Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables.

However the setting in XCode appears correct, In the linking section I found

"Don't Create Position Independent Executables" which is set to NO.

(Double negatives YUK).

Answer (score 2):

You may be receiving this Apple warning not because your Application itself, but because a 3rd party library that was not compiled as PIE. For example, if you are using Marmalade SDK Engine you will receive this warning (they will fix it in september).

But you can try adding more compiler flags in your Build Settings:

In **Other C flags** you may put the flag: **-fPIC**

In **Other Warning flags** you may put: **-Wl,--emit-relocs** and **-Wl,--warn-shared-textrel**

To see if your app is PIE:

```
otool -hf /path/to/your/App.app/app
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1788/_index.html

Comment: how do you know whether a 3rd party library was compiled with PIE?

Comment: thank you, these flags worked. What do they mean? Can they adversely effect my app?

Comment: Scratch that, the command tool shows my app has the PIE flag, however when I upload the app the the App Store I still receive a warning about PIE of the framework

Comment: I have a problem. I can't seem do find "Don't Create Position Independent Executables" anywhere... where should I search for it? :/

Answer (score 0):

I got respond from Apple with

> Non-PIE Binary - The executable 'ProductManualApp.app' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables.

From my research from Google, lots of people said it related "Don't Create Position Independent Executables". I think should keep it default, which is 'No'

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue even though I did everything as stated at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1788/_index.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013354