# xCode 4.6.1 - Don't Create Position Independent Executables. Can't enable

Tags: xcode, position, app-store, executable, xcode4.6

I got an mail from App Store :

```
Non-PIE Binary - The executable '***.app' is not a Position Independent Executable.
```

I set Dependent Code to **NO**. But I can't find Don't Create Position Independent Executables 
in Build Settings - Linking. There is only Other Linker Flags.

Where can I find this option?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Build Settings of the project target.

Make sure that the IOS deployment target is over 4.3 or OSX is over 10.7. Generate Position-Dependent Code is set to "NO", and Don't Create Position Independent Executables is also "NO"

If this doesn't fix you problem it might be that libraries that you have included in your project don't have these setting.   [What is the correct Xcode setting for Position Independent Executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518204/what-is-the-correct-xcode-setting-for-position-independent-executables) might help.